# How to insert pictures into a docx file on the same horizontal line using python-docx?

Tags: python, ms-word, docx

I can insert multiple images into a word document using the code that follows but they appear beneath each other. Is there a way of inserting them so that they are next to each other instead?

```
from docx import Document
from docx.shared import Inches

document = Document()

document.add_heading('Document Title', 0)

document.add_picture(image_filepath, width=Inches(1.25))
document.add_picture(image_filepath, width=Inches(1.25))

document.save(doc_filepath)
```

Answer (score 4):

One way to do it is to create transparent table and add images to cells:

```
from docx import Document

document = Document()
tables = document.tables
table = document.add_table(rows=1, cols=2)
row_cells = table.add_row().cells

for i, image in enumerate(['image1.jpg', 'image2.jpg']):
    paragraph = row_cells[i].paragraphs[0]
    run = paragraph.add_run()
    run.add_picture(image)
document.save('doc.docx')
```

That's what you'll get for instance:

[image]